# Why SSDT BI installation needs SQL Server installation?

Tags: business-intelligence, sql-server-data-tools, bids, ssdt-bi

Why SSDT BI installation needs SQL Server installation as we are ultimately going to deploy BI packages on server where SQL Server would already be available?
I need it for SSRS.

Comment: SSIS? SSAS Tabular? SSAS Multidimensional? SSRS? Which are you using?

Comment: SSRS - I have edited question also.

Answer (score 1):

SSDT BI does not require SQL Server installed. SSRS does. The tool allows you to develop your reports and when it comes to the Deploy point, you will need an SSRS instance which requires SQL Server. SSDT BI may install a local instance of SQL Server Express, but it is not used for SSRS but for SQL Tools.